# How to detect which element body or html need to be scrolled

Tags: javascript

In Fireofx and IE to get the scrollTop you need to get it from html and in chrome from body element.

Is there a way to detect that without browser sniffing?

```js
var html = document.querySelector('html');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  input.value = html.scrollTop + ' ' + body.scrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

I need to detect which element to scroll because I need to change scrollTop from my code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just test either for truthiness (assuming `0` means not there)?

```js
function getScrollTop() {
  return html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;
}

var html = document.querySelector('html');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  input.value = getScrollTop();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

As far as updating the scroll top, you can create a setter function that sets the appropriate browser property. The way you build this setter is by manually triggering a scroll when the page loads and determining which property changed.

```js
function setScrollTopUpdater(cb) {
  var html = document.querySelector('html');
  var body = document.querySelector('body');

  // temporary listener to determine which scroll property updated
  // and create an appropriate scroll top setter
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function temp() {
    if (html.scrollTop > 0) {
      // return a function that updates the firefox prop
      cb(function(x) {
        html.scrollTop = x;
      });
    } else {
      // return a function that updates the chrome prop
      cb(function(x) {
        body.scrollTop = x;
      });
    }
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', temp);
  });

  // trigger scroll by 1 pixel
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);
}

var updateScrollTop = null;
setScrollTopUpdater(function(updater) {
  updateScrollTop = updater;
});

setTimeout(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function demo() {
    document.querySelector('input').value = window.scrollY;
  });
  updateScrollTop(200);
}, 2000)
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #018bbc;
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Will set scrollTop to 200"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that I also want to change scrollTop from my code, that's way I need to detect which element to scroll.

Comment: @jcubic check out my edit. The main idea is to manually trigger a scroll when the page loads to determine which property changed and then use that information to create a function that will update correct property when you need to.

Comment: Wow, my wekit userAgent check is much simpler. And it work without the need for scroll event to happen but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yup, thats definitely the easier option, I was just suggesting an alternative way  as you've requested :)

Answer (score 1):

If life was simple, you could use this event handler property. But I.E throws a spanner in the works with no browser support for it. You could of course always write some code to step around IE if this isn't available.

```
if (!('scrollingElement' in document)) (function() {
   alert('IE is a pain in the arse');
}


window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
   alert(event.scrollingElement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check for both values of `html.scrollTop` and `body.scrollTop`:

- `if` they're **both 0** than the **scrolltop is 0**

using `!html.scrollTop` will return `true` if it's value is equals to zero or undefined

- `else if` `html.scrollTop` is bigger than `0` (exist) than **scrolltop is html.scrollTop**
- `else if` `body.scrollTop` is bigger than `0` (chrome) than **scrolltop is body.scrollTop**

in this example I'm storing scrolltop value in a var called `myScrollTop`

```
var myScrollTop

if (!html.scrollTop && !body.scrollTop) {
    myScrollTop = 0
} else if (html.scrollTop) {
    myScrollTop = html.scrollTop
} else if (body.scrollTop) {
    myScrollTop = body.scrollTop
}
```

you can also wrap the code in a function and return the value to the caller

```
function myScrollTop() {
    if (!html.scrollTop && !body.scrollTop) {
        return 0
    } else if (html.scrollTop) {
        return html.scrollTop
    } else if (body.scrollTop) {
        return body.scrollTop
    }
}
```

or the shorter version

```
function myScrollTop() {
    return html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0
}
```

now you can get the value of scroll top by calling `myScrollTop()`

```
console.log(myScrollTop())
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: done, will try to explain more in future answers. thanks for the remarks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this hack, it add pre tag that trigger scrollbar, set scrollTop and check which element have it changed:

```js
var html = $('html');
var body = $('body');
var scrollTop = body.scrollTop() || html.scrollTop();
var pre = $('<pre/>').appendTo('body');
pre.html(new Array(1000).join('\n'));
$('body,html').scrollTop(10);
var scrollObject;
if (body.scrollTop() == 10) {
  console.log('body');
  scrollObject = body;
  body.scrollTop(scrollTop);
} else if ($('html').scrollTop() == 10) {
  console.log('html');
  scrollObject = html;
  html.scrollTop(scrollTop);
}
pre.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```